# Expo Go on Android Manifest is not valid JSON

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am currently creating a cross platform app with expo. The app was started with the tamagui solito starter at https://github.com/tamagui/tamagui/tree/master/starters/next-expo-solito
I have added some screens and the app is working on expo go on ios and on web. However I cannot get the Android version to even start. I have tried both expo go, and creating a development build with eas. The eas build crashes on open and the expo go errors out with

`Uncaught error: java.io.IOException: Manifest string is not a valid JSONObject or JSONArray: <DOCTYPE html>...`

Here is my eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true,
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "env": {
        "TAMAGUI_TARGET": "native"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      },
      "env": {
        "TAMAGUI_TARGET": "native"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am running the expo server in WSL2 if this affects anything.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.